# Quarto continue rendering

Tags: r, rendering, quarto

I'm trying to compile [r4ds book](https://github.com/hadley/r4ds) with `quarto render`.

However some files have some problems that need fixing.

The problem is that, every time I run `quarto render`, the compilation starts over from the beginning.

Is there a way to continue the compilation from the last broken file?

For example, if the compilation stops at `webscraping.qml`, to restart from there?

Comment: This might [help](https://books.ropensci.org/targets/literate-programming.html#quarto-targets).

Comment: The quarto documentation on [Managing Execution](https://quarto.org/docs/projects/code-execution.html) - in particular, "freezing" and _maybe_ "caching" - seems like it might be helpful for your case.